# bpy.path.abspath is appears to be messing up

Tags: python, scripting, path, file-browser

I am working on an addon and I have a **StringProperty** that is a **File_Path**, you select the file and it reads the xml at the location. These string property's automatically use relative paths, so my code is if "//" is in the path it automatically uses `bpy.path.abspath` on it to convert to an absolute path, but it dosesn't seem to be working right.

The .blend is in *D:\Pictures\3D Models\Models\file.blend*
The file selected is at *D:\Pictures\main_car\file.xml*
The output from the **StringProperty** is *//..\..\main_car\file.xml*

When this output is converted using `bpy.path.abspath` it becomes:
*D:\Pictures\3D Models\Models\..\..\main_car\file.xml*
not where the file actually is. It is like it isn't backing up far enough before it goes into the *main_car* folder

Comment: Try using `os.path.abspath(string)`

Comment: the just returns `\\..\..\main_car\file.xml`

Comment: I'm guessing ´..´ means "The previous directory", like in a command line/shell; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)#Options_(version_specific)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someonewithpc said, `..` means one directory up. Thus,

```
D:\Pictures\3D Models\Models\..\..\main_car\file.xml
```

is the same directory as

```
D:\Pictures\main_car\file.xml
```

although the path is overly complicated (not cleaned up).

You can shorten it by `realpath()` or `abspath()` from `os.path`:

```
import bpy
import os
os.path.realpath(bpy.path.abspath(your_path))
```